# Configuring system tests in junit

Tags: junit, junit4, system-testing

We currently have a dedicated tool for running system tests on our web services, but I've been thinking of re-writing it to be hostable within jUnit4.

This would give us several advantages, including the full power of Java to set up and assert results, as well as hopefully a simpler method of running the tests (both from CI and the IDE).

However, the tests would need a URL configured for it to test against (it is currently too impractical to initialise a local servlet for testing). Given this, is it still a good idea to try and host it in jUnit? If so, what's the best way to add the configuration?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you will be running your unit tests. I normally use maven, then you have a test/resources directory where you can store the test setup.

You can use spring with AbstractDependencyInjectionSpringContextTests (which gives you spring-injected configuration, you can swap the main spring config for a test version)

[Here is a dicussion about configuring junit in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/633700/automatically-add-properties-when-running-junit-in-eclipse)

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing non-unit testing, [TestNG](http://testng.org) might be a better option than JUnit. More specifically, data providers seem like they would be a good fit in the scenario you describe ([example here](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parameters-dataproviders)). Data providers can retrieve their data pretty much from anywhere: a text/properties/xml/Excel file, a database, a remote host, etc...